# how to reshape a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a matrix that is 321*531(1*170451) but it has some nan values, so I have to eliminate these nan values,,so I use this code in matlab:

```
m=isfinite(x);

n=x(m)';
```

then my matrix turns to 1*75638 and I don't know how to reshape this matrix to 321*531.

Comment: Well if you remove elements from a matrix it can't possibly be reshaped back to the original size.

Comment: what would you like to have in place of the nans/infinites in your new matrix?